# Best way to allow a user to select a library, such as Documents or Music, from a Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

^^^ This is not a duplicate ^^^

I have a `FolderBrowserDialog` that my users can use to select folders, which is great.

But, I also want them to be able to select libraries. For instance, they should be able to select the *Documents* library, or the *Pictures* library.

What is the best way to achieve this in c# for a WinForms application?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I think the OP means the libraries you see when you open a windows explorer window (like Documents, Music, Picures, Video), like in this screen shot: http://tinypic.com/r/30w2ebp/8

Comment: Yes. My users can easily select a directory because I give them a FolderBrowserDialog control. Once they select a directory, they can click OK and the application will scan the files within their selected directory. But, I also want them to be able to select a library in addition to a directory, like the Music or Pictures library so that the application can scan the files within the folders that belong to those specific libraries. The problem is that the FolderBrowserDialog does not permit the selection of Libraries, and I am wondering: what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that does not answer my questions, and it is not a duplicate. I simply want my user to be able to select a library and have the FolderBrowserDialog (or some other control) return a collection of the folders contained in the library to my method so that I can iterate through them.